# React router renders a blank page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

I'm trying to learn ReactJS and the new React router is really confusing me when it comes to nested routing.

Simply I want to have three routes as follows

   `/ -  home Page 
   /users - list all the users
   /users/add - add user form`

You can see the complete code sample below

[View code in codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/2opo8n2kvp)

When I hit `/` or `/users` it works fine. But, when I reach `/users/add` router renders a blank page instead of AddUser component.

I know I can define absolute routes in index.js itself like `/users` and `/users/add`. But I was kind of thinking to have a more maintainable way to define routers inside of child components.

Any idea how to tackle this problem?

```
// src/index.js 
render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
      <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
      <Route path="/about" component={About} />
      <Route exact path="/users" component={UserLayout} />
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);



class UserLayout extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div className="users">
          <Route exact path={this.props.match.path} component={Users} />
          <Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/add`} component={AddUser} />
        </div>
      );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your **src/index.js** file
`<Route exact path="/users" component={UserLayout} />`

Should be

`<Route path="/users" component={UserLayout} />`

What is happening is your **exact** makes it match only on `/users` so when you update the path to `/users/add` it won't match the path anymore

Comment: I have another question. What if we add a nested route (If you see on bills component in the same URL) how to render the add bills component properly?
I have not used a layout for both Bills and AddBills in this one.
Thank you.

Comment: Is this what you mean? You want to render the Bills component. You don't mean that its a nested route since its going to /bills. But if I'm understanding what you want is to add this 
`import Bills from "./components/Bills/Bills";`
`<Route exact path="/bills" component={Bills} />`

Comment: No, I want to happen same thing as previously but, this time without the layout which render Bills and ```AddBills``` component. 


I have define ```AddBills``` component in the ```<Route />``` inside ```AllBills``` component. When I visit ```/bills```, I want to show ```AllBills``` (which happens now) and when I visit ```/bills/add```, I want to show ```AddBills``` component (right now, it's showing the same AllBills component).

Is this possible? Or, do I need to have a common layout like before and render respective components?

Comment: Exactly. So to achieve that, we have to define the ```<Route />``` at ```index.js``` file. Isn't it? 

No way to define it in ```AllBills``` component and have the same functionality unless I go for a sub layout like I did it in users scenario. Isn't it?

Comment: Yup the only way to do that is to make a sub layout or define it in the index.js